# Table data to JSON format

Tags: json

What would be the correct or best JSON format for the following table.

[How to convert table to JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kCyw.png)

Comment: What does this table represent?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and include details of what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Not a lot of details to go on, but (Please note, ordered lists are required):

```
{
    "Product1": {
       "UNLABELLED FIELD": [2.625, 2.5, 2.375, 2.25],
       "LOCK": ["PRICE", "PRICE", "PRICE", "PRICE"],
       "15": [-0.5..., ...],
       "30": [-0.4..., ...],
       "45": [-0.3..., ...],
    },
    "Product2": {
       ...
    },
    "Product3": {
       ...
    },
}
```

And if you can't have unordered lists:

```
{
    "ProductList": [
        "Product1": {
            "UNLABELLED FIELD": 2.625,
            "LOCK": "PRICE",
            "15": -0.5...,
            "30": -0.4...,
            "45": -0.3...,
        }, ...
    ]

}
```

However, I would recommend keeping and processing in CSV format